# Automatically activating disabled shopping cart pricing rule in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I had a shopping cart price rule running last week which automatically applied **40%** off at the checkout on full price product. This was expired on **last Friday at 12:00 PM** but I also disabled the promo at next day. After some days I have just noticed that the promo is again applying. Anyone faced this issue? My Magento Version is **Magento 2.1.7** 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the issue was future schedules are automatically enabling if the scheduled time has come. Here I did the logic is forcefully deactivating all future schedules if the status of current cart rule changed to inactive. Tested and working fine.